# Vedi nota a piè pagina 3? O vedi nota numero 3 a piè pagina? O cosa?

Tags: word-usage, typography

In inglese,

> See footnote 3

è abbastanza inequivocabile: si andrà a cercare la nota a piè pagina numerata col numero 3.

Ma in italiano non sono sicuro che suoni bene, inquanto

> Vedi nota a piè pagina 3

mi fa pensare che uno potrebbe capire "vedi la nota a piè pagina che si trova a pagina 3".

C'è **un modo consolidato** per riferirsi ad una nota a piè pagina numerata in un documento in italiano?

---

Ovviamente spesso una nota a piè pagina non necessita di riferimento¹, ma ci sono casi particolari²

(¹) una nota a piè pagina

(²) vedi nota 1

Comment: Ma io eviterei proprio di dire 'a pié di pagina', è pesante, in genere non si usa, (tanto dove stanno le note nel libro si vede): *Vedi nota 3*, e basta.

Comment: @BakerStreet mi ha tolto le parole di bocca: In genere le si chiama “note” e basta, che siano in fondo alla pagina, al capitolo o al libro.

Comment: Comunque, anche se c'è chi dice “a piè pagina”, è più corretto “a piè di pagina”; e “numerata” non “numberata”.

Comment: Anche io ho sempre detto e sentito 'a piè **di **pagina'. Comunque per me non c'è dubbio, note e basta, 'note a piè di pagina' è  linguaggio formale da tipografo (infatti lo si trova nel Word, che è un programma di scrittura) , o eccesso di zelo in una  traduzione troppo letterale dall'inglese (una traduzione  non buona).

Comment: Sono ricordi molto lontani, ma mi è stato detto che nella critica letteraria e nelle edizioni di opere classiche, vengono adoperati spesso tipi di note diversi (a pié di pagina, a fine capitolo, a fine libro etc.). Magari qualcuno che conosce quel tipo di letteratura può spiegare come vengono dati i riferimenti. A parte casi di questo genere, sono d'accordo che usare semplicemente "nota" è da preferirsi.

Comment: @DenisNardin, il libro a cui mi riferisco è tipo così. Ha note a piè pagina e sezione delle note a fine libro.

Comment: Ma usano numerazioni distinte (per esempio i classici *, †, ‡ etc. per quelle a piè di pagina e numeri per le altre)? Se no, è un delirio, comunque le chiami.

Comment: @DaG, note a piè di pagina usano simboli. Poi ci sono le note a fine libro, raggruppate per capitolo, che hanno il riferimento alla pagina dalla quale sono citate.

Comment: Benissimo, grazie, @Enlico.